# Displaying CAknInformationNote on device

Tags: c++, symbian

I am fetching the call-logs, appending them on information note using:

```
CAknInformationNote* note = new (ELeave) CAknInformationNote;
note->ExecuteLD(callLogs);
```

I perfectly run on emulator (show all call-logs on note) but nothing shows up when run on the actual device (a Nokia N73). Any ideas?

Comment: Have you done and tracing or on device debugging to find out if this line actually runs and if so, does it Leave?

Answer (score 1):

i think you should use some kind of file logging(you can even use RFile) and see till what point your application executing.i am assuming you dont see a crash/panic on hardware.i doubt if you are able to get the call logs properly first on device.